# javascript error on command button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

[image]    {!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/39.0/connection.js')}

```
var rec = 
'{!JSENCODE(TEXT(Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c.Reason_for_cancelation__c))}';
if(rec != "--None--" ) {
HYPERLINK("/apex/Apttus__AgreementCancel?id=" &Id, 
IMAGE("/resource/Apttus__Button_CancelRequest", "Cancel Request"), "_self");
}
else {
alert('You cannot do this');
 }


ERROR-<span class="validStyle">No syntax errors in merge fields or functions. 
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your merge field needs to be quoted and escaped:

```
var rec = {!Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c.Reason_for_cancelation__c};
```

just dumps the value of the field directly into the JavaScript, likely producing syntax errors. It should be

```
var rec = '{! JSENCODE(TEXT(Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c.Reason_for_cancelation__c)) }';
```

[`JSENCODE()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm#!) escapes backslashes for you.

The `HYPERLINK()` and `IMAGE()` functions are not defined outside of a merge field context `{! }`, but aren't meaningful here in a JavaScript button anyway. It's not clear what you're aiming to do; if you wish to do a redirect, do it via JavaScript rather than attempting to use a merge function. If you're aiming to generate content to insert in the page, you may want a formula field or an embedded Visualforce page.

Comment: <span class="errorStyle">Error: Field Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c.Reason_for_cancelation__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions. <a href="javascript:openPopupFocusEscapePounds('https://help.salesforce.com/apex/htdoor?loc=help&target=tips_on_building_formulas.htm%23picklists_and_msps§ion=Customizing&language=en_US&release=220.17&instance=CS53', 'Help', 1024, 768, 'width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,directories=no,location=yes,dependant=no', false, false);">Tell me more</a></span>

Comment: Thanks    @David Reed  .    Picklists are not supporting ,Is there any workaround  for this ?

Comment: Wrap it in a `TEXT()` call, as always with picklist fields.

Comment: No syntax errors ,But on page its displaying errors as showing in the screenshot above. Please can you look in it .